# URL route with two variables doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

a have a problem with ASP.net MVC url routing. I have created this route (it is first route in my RegisterRoutes method:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Activate",
    "Account/Activate/{username}/{key}",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Activate", username = "", key = "" },
    new { username = @"([a-z0-9\.-]+)", key = @"([a-z0-9\.-]+)" } 
);
```

but when i try to go tu URL like this:

```
http://localhost:63779/acount/activate/test/hLMqWJrwp1dK5xTqbGkP5kzUNQ4
```

it returns 404 error

(with UrlParameter.Optional I've got the same result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your regular expression is incorrect.  Use the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Activate",
    "Account/Activate/{username}/{key}",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Activate" },
    new { username = @"^[\w\.]+$", key = @"^[\w\.]+$" }
);
```

The regex shown will match a string containing any word character (\w is the same as [A-Za-z0-9_]) or a dot, which has no spaces or other characters.

**UPDATE**

After testing the route and copying it into my answer, I forgot to change the controller value to "Account".  I have updated the route above.

Comment: Thanks for tip, but it still returns 404. I tried it with correct RegEx but still same result.

Comment: I noticed that I put the incorrect controller value in the route.  I updated my answer.  Please check it with the correct controller value.

Comment: Thanks, i'm really blind. How i could works when i have Account in my route and acount in URL.

Comment: I made the exact same mistake when I first tested the route.  Please mark as answered if this helped you.